# Why does npm start ignore escaped backticks from argument?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a super simple `index.js` file that outputs the first argument it receives:

```
// Args 0 & 1 are /usr/bin/node and path to file
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```

When I run the following:

```
node index.js test``backticks
```

the output is `testbackticks`, and as expected, the backticks are ignored.
Calling this again, with escaping this time:

```
node index.js test\`\`backticks
```

the output is ``` test``backticks ```.

My `package.json` has a start script like so:

```
"start": "node ./index.js"
```

Calling ``` npm start -- test``backticks ``` will result in them being ignored, just like with the node.js call.
However, calling this with escaping:

```
npm start -- test\`\`backticks
```

Also results in the same output, which is simply:

> testbackticks

With the backticks ignored as well.

Escaping npm start with double or single quotes worked fine, it is just the backticks that are ignored.
Why does calling `npm start` and `node` produces different results and how come backticks can't be escaped in npm start ?
Lastly, how can I, if possible, pass a string with backticks as an argument to `npm start` ?